# C# app.config format issue

Tags: c#, xml, events, app-config, handler

If the app.config format is wrong, for example, not a correct format XML file, application will fail from loading. Are there any ways to let me know such issue -- for example, receiving some events (so that I could write file log and event log to record this issue) if app.config loads error because of a mal-formatted XML file?

thanks in advance,
George

My code and app.config looks like this, but no exception is thrown.

```
    class Program
    {
        public static void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            return;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += MyEventHandler;

            return;
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Within your application start up, e.g. within a static constructor of the main class. you can define it as

```
  AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
  currentDomain.UnhandledException += MyHandler; // define MyHanlder somewhere.
```

to catch the ConfigurationErrorsException due to the config.

Comment: You should note that when you got an AppDomain.UnhandledException you application WILL be terminated no matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks codemeit!

I have written code like this, but how could I know it is exception from wrong app.config format?
        public static void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            return;
        }

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Alex! But how could we distinguish from application configuration loading error because wrong XML format between other types of exceptions?

Comment: try to see whats in sender and eventArgs?

Comment: I have posted my code and the wrong format app.config, but no exception is thrown. Any ideas why?